# Return 1 if any bit is set otherwise 0 using a logical operation

Tags: bit, logical-operators

EDIT: the point is about answering the question not giving alternatives like we have meat instead of fish, I know there are simpler alternatives about it

**Huge thanks to abelenky for his answer and to David Norris as well**

---

For a specified number I would like to return 1 if that number is not 0 otherwise return 0 and without having to use a `for...loop`, `if` or `bool`.

In [this document](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/) it does work fine except for 0 :

> Bit Hack #8. Right propagate the rightmost 1-bit.
>
> ```
> y = x | (x-1)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> This is not a clean hack, tho, as it produces all 1's if x = 0.

The best thing I came up with is the following (for a byte type) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    int o =
        ((i & (1 << 7)) >> 7) |
        ((i & (1 << 6)) >> 6) |
        ((i & (1 << 5)) >> 5) |
        ((i & (1 << 4)) >> 4) |
        ((i & (1 << 3)) >> 3) |
        ((i & (1 << 2)) >> 2) |
        ((i & (1 << 1)) >> 1) |
        ((i & (1 << 0)) >> 0);
    Debug.Assert((i == 0 & o == 0) || (i != 0 && o == 1));
    Console.WriteLine(@"i {0:D3} o {1:D3}", i, o);
}
```

However, looking at the disassembly it produces all this code :

```
        int o =
            ((i & (1 << 7)) >> 7) |
            ((i & (1 << 6)) >> 6) |
            ((i & (1 << 5)) >> 5) |
            ((i & (1 << 4)) >> 4) |
            ((i & (1 << 3)) >> 3) |
            ((i & (1 << 2)) >> 2) |
            ((i & (1 << 1)) >> 1) |
            ((i & (1 << 0)) >> 0);
0000021f  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
00000222  mov         edx,80h 
00000227  and         eax,edx 
00000229  sar         eax,7 
0000022c  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
0000022f  mov         ecx,40h 
00000234  and         edx,ecx 
00000236  sar         edx,6 
00000239  or          eax,edx 
0000023b  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
0000023e  mov         ecx,20h 
00000243  and         edx,ecx 
00000245  sar         edx,5 
00000248  or          eax,edx 
0000024a  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
0000024d  mov         ecx,10h 
00000252  and         edx,ecx 
00000254  sar         edx,4 
00000257  or          eax,edx 
00000259  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
0000025c  mov         ecx,8 
00000261  and         edx,ecx 
00000263  sar         edx,3 
00000266  or          eax,edx 
00000268  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
0000026b  mov         ecx,4 
00000270  and         edx,ecx 
00000272  sar         edx,2 
00000275  or          eax,edx 
00000277  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
0000027a  mov         ecx,2 
0000027f  and         edx,ecx 
00000281  sar         edx,1 
00000283  or          eax,edx 
00000285  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch] 
00000288  mov         ecx,1 
0000028d  and         edx,ecx 
0000028f  or          eax,edx 
00000291  mov         dword ptr [ebp-70h],eax
```

Is there another way using some clever **logical operation** that would not produce that many instructions ?

Note, the point here is not about reducing the number of instructions produced for the sake of performance, rather to know whether there as simpler way to do this.

Some people hinted to convert the number to a boolean but unfortunately this is not possible in C#, there are also the `Convert.ToInt` and `Convert.ToBoolean` methods that could be used for this but I don't want to use them.

Comment: I don't quite get your question here. Do you mean that you want to check whether or not any bit inside a integer is set as 1? What about just using `return i!=0`?

Comment: That would return a bool which in return would need an `if` to convert it back to either a 0 or 1.

Comment: This question doesn't seem C# specific at all. Its all about bit-twiddling, regardless of language.  I'm removing the C# tag.

Comment: "I don't want to do it the right (or easiest) way. Instead, I want to write many unnecessary, needless, and much more difficult to read and understand lines of code.". Is that right? (Well, it's either that or "My homework assignment is...", I suppose.)

Comment: I might deceive you but this ain't homework.

Comment: Not homework? Well, you could have fooled me.

Comment: @Mr Lister:  There are plenty of good applications for non-branching code, especially in extremely high performance computing, or in hard-wired circuits without a Von Newman architecture.  (of course, since the original question was in C#, this doesn't seem to be one of those applications)

Comment: @MrLister It's amazing to see how someone in SO can be flagged as 'a student' by just being curious about an alternative way of doing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Returns 1 for any non-zero number, 0 for zero.
int AnyBitSet(int x)
{
    return !!x;
}
```

If `X` is zero, `!X` is 1, and `!!X` is zero.
If `X` is non-zero, `!X` is 0, and `!!X` is exactly 1, regardless of the original `x`.

Comment: Unfortunately it produces 1 for even numbers and 0 for odd numbers.

Comment: I think it might be a little more complicated than needed. You can do it by only looking at the sign, not the lowest bit. x => !(x & 0x80000000) ^ ((x-1) & 0x80000000) >> 31

Comment: @Aybe:  If you try that code, be sure you test `INT_MIN`.  It probably won't work for underflow.

Answer (score 4):

**Your question was:** *"Return 1 if any bit is set otherwise 0"*

**The answer is:**

```
int AnyBitSet(int x)
{
    return (x == 0)? 0 : 1;
}
```

*(perhaps you'd like to clarify your question?)*

Comment: I've updated the question (I don't want to use a boolean in this case).

Comment: I don't understand why you "don't want to use a boolean" operation. It is the best solution to whatever you are trying to ask.

Comment: I've asked about fish, not meat. Of course there's another way but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @Aybe, you asked how to return 1 if any bit is set using some "logical operation". That sounds a lot like Boolean to me.

Answer (score 2):

OK, how about using the .NET Framework...

```
return Math.Abs(Math.Sign(x));
```

Comment: You should have been more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```c
int IsZero(int x)
{
    return ((x & -x) - 1) >> 31;
}
```

x & -x isolates the least significant 1 if such exists (case a) otherwise it is 0 (case b). Then subtracting 1 will remove sign bit (case a) or results in -1 (case b). The final shift gives sign bit so 0 in case a and 1 in case b. This gives the opposite result to what you asked, but it can always be switched.

```c
int IsNonZero(int x)
{
    return IsZero(x) ^ 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public static uint OneIfNonzero( uint x )
{
    x |= x >> 16;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 1;
    return x & 1;
}
```

The idea here is to use a series of ORs to propagate all the bits down to the least-significant bit. After the series of ORs is finished, the least-significant bit equals the OR of all 32 original bits. The remaining bits are then stripped off using the final AND.

The same idea could be adapted for use with numeric types of other sizes (`ulong`, `ushort`, etc.) or signed types.

Comment: No it isn't. You're individually shifting over each bit. Mine shifts by half each time, which results in log(*n*) operations instead of *n* (for an *n*-bit number). I don't think you'll find anything simpler without using conditionals (which would be the altogether better solution anyway).

Answer (score -2):

it cannot be done in a single logical operation - all logical operations are either bitwise, iterating like a for loop over the inputs, or they are cumulative, which also does not help your problem. You need a conditional (if / then) to solve this properly...

Comment: Not necessarily and there's no need to use conditionals, that's the whole point of this question.

Comment: **Absolutely not true.**  My answer does it with `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`, `BitShift`, and `-1` operations only.